# How Angular can not find the component factory for my component despite it has been declared in the entryComponents option of my Module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to show a component in a [ngx-bootstrap's modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) but how can I dynamically create it ?

I have tried to declare the component in the `entryComponents` option of the `RegMktRiskHomeModule` but it doesn't work either. The only way I found for now is to declare the `ScenariosGraphComponent` in the `AppModule` just like I've done it in `RegMktRiskCommonModule`.

Could that be related to the fact that `RegMktRiskHomeModule` is imported in `HomeModule` and that this `HomeModule` is lazy-loaded by the application ?

Here is my code (roughly):

`reg-mkt-risk-common.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ScenariosGraphComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ScenariosGraphComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ScenariosGraphComponent
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class RegMktRiskCommonModule { }
```

`reg-mkt-risk-home.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        RegulatoryMarketRiskHomeComponent,
        OverviewGridComponent // <-- component who actually show ScenariosGraphComponent in a modal
    ],
    exports: [
        RegulatoryMarketRiskHomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...,
        RegMktRiskCommonModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
    ]
})
export class RegMktRiskHomeModule { }
```

Here is the actual error message:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for ScenariosGraphComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:9659)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:9697)
    at ComponentLoader.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-component-loader.js.ComponentLoader._getContentRef (ngx-bootstrap-component-loader.js:411)
    at ComponentLoader.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-component-loader.js.ComponentLoader.show (ngx-bootstrap-component-loader.js:152)
    at BsModalService.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-modal.js.BsModalService._showModal (ngx-bootstrap-modal.js:927)
    at BsModalService.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-modal.js.BsModalService.show (ngx-bootstrap-modal.js:853)
    at Object.action (overview-grid.options.ts:48)
    at MenuItemComponent.push../node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/menuItemComponent.js.MenuItemComponent.onOptionSelected (menuItemComponent.js:102)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the entryComponent has to be listed in the module where it should be used.
In your case it has to be listed in the home module but not (neccesarily) in the common module where it is defined.

Comment: @Scorpioo590 you mean like in Tony's answer ? I already tried that and it doesn't work either :-(

Comment: I edited my question, has my pb anything to do with the fact that ```RegMktRiskHomeModule``` is imported in the lazy-loaded ```HomeModule```.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to import the MatDialogModule in the module of the component that opens the dialog. The error that Angular generates in that case can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        RegulatoryMarketRiskHomeComponent,
        OverviewGridComponent,
        ScenariosGraphComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ScenariosGraphComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        RegulatoryMarketRiskHomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...,
        RegMktRiskCommonModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
    ]
})
export class RegMktRiskHomeModule { }
```

So you can remove ScenariosGraphComponent in your RegMktRiskCommonModule

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work either. I still have the same error. By the way, the reason I created the module ```RegMktRiskCommonModule``` is because ```ScenariosGraphComponent``` will be used in different features on my application (and probably other components).

Comment: I edited my question, has my pb anything to do with the fact that ```RegMktRiskHomeModule``` is imported in the lazy-loaded ```HomeModule```.

Answer (score 0):

If your Module is lazy loaded and you need to share services among lazy loaded modules, So please you a shared module and add common components and services there and then import shared module in app module